# charts.js Stacked Bar Graphs - selecting row and dataset selected

Tags: javascript, chart.js

We created a stacked bar graph, but I need a way of identifying which bar and section/element of the bar I've selected. I can work out the bar no problem. so in the following image that would be 4 - so I can retrieve the label "Report Edit Complete":

Like this:

[image]

If I click on the pink I want to retrieve the label for the 3rd element/dataset "6-9 weeks". Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: the easiest ( and widely used ) way is to definde element datasets. `<div data-label="Label" data-group="pink"></div>` and then retrieve it through the event ( click in this case ) i.e. `el.addEventListener('click', e=>{ let label = e.target.dataset.label; let group = e.target.dataset.group });` .. and you set in js by simply going `el.dataset.label = 'Label'`

Comment: Thanks  zergski ... my knowledge of Javascript is relatively new and I can't get my head around this, do you know if there is a working example somewhere on the internet that I can look at and try to follow?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using a custom onclick handler like so:

```
options: {
    onClick: (evt,elements,chart) => {
        const clickedPoint = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);
      const label = chart.data.datasets[clickedPoint[0].datasetIndex].label;
      
      alert(label)
    }
}
```

working example:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'red',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            },
      {
            label: '# of Points',
            data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'blue',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    onClick: (evt,elements,chart) => {
        const clickedPoint = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);
      const label = chart.data.datasets[clickedPoint[0].datasetIndex].label;
      
      alert(label)
    },
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
        y: {
        stacked: true
      },
      x: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js" integrity="sha512-opXrgVcTHsEVdBUZqTPlW9S8+99hNbaHmXtAdXXc61OUU6gOII5ku/PzZFqexHXc3hnK8IrJKHo+T7O4GRIJcw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/y2rnophL/10/

Comment: Thank you LeeLenalee, I'll give this a try, thanks for your replay.